# SQL - How to run when you have nested select and output returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code like below as I am working on some complex conditions.

```
select *, (select * from table b where conditions are met)
from table a
```

The code meets my needs but the problem is that it fails if `(select * from table b where conditions are met)` returns more than 1 row. Is there a way to work around that? Is there a way to duplicate rows from `table a` if the second select clause is going to return more than 1 row?

I tried running `(select * from table b where conditions are met)` part first and then doing left join with `table b` but that takes way longer time and I would like to avoid if possible

Comment: You would probably need to provide a minimum reproducible example that demonstrate your use case. This pseudo-code does not give enough information about the problem, and how you want to solve it.

Comment: Try Google for "t-sql subquery return multiple rows". There are examples there

Comment: You could always do a SELECT TOP 1 *

Comment: Either limit sub query results to 1 row or rewrite the query to use join (if two tables are unrelated use a cross join)

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve the issue would be to serialize tableb to a JSON object using FOR JSON.  Something like this

```
select *, (select * from table b where conditions are met FOR JSON PATH) json_name
from table a
```

When assigning JSON to a variable or storing in SQL Server it should always be NVARCHAR(MAX) data type.  Also, it's always necessary to give columns an explicit name in order to serialize correctly and without causing an error.  So it would make sense to expand the wildcard in the SELECT statement, if that's an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try running this as a `left join`:

```
select *, b.*
from table a left join
     b
     on . . . and <conditions>
```

Or using `outer apply`:

```
select *, b.*
from table a outer apply
     (select * from table b where conditions are met) b;
```